# How to get checked box order by selecting first

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get checked checkboxes in an array but I want them to be ordered in the order they are selected.

For example, I have 3 checkboxes—

```
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck[]">
```

—and I selected Check 2 then Check 3 then Check 1.

I want result to be in array like this ('2','3','1')

I use this function but it's not get them to order

```
var list = new Array();
    $('input[name="mycheck"]:checked').each(function() {
        list.push([$(this).val()]);
    });

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Why do your checkboxes have the same name? Radio buttons should share the same name, not checkboxes

Comment: @j08691 because i want them to be in array, []

Comment: Simply put a `list.sort((a, b) => a-b)` before your `console.log`

Comment: `$('input[name="mycheck"]:checked')` gets the elements in the order they exist in the HTML. You could update some kind of `data-order` value which is the order they were clicked in and then sort before the `.each`.

Comment: Does the resulting javascript "order checked by user" array need to be sent along with the form? OR are you only using the array elsewhere in this page's javascript.

Comment: A word of warning if you intend to use this for users to sort items: The order is not visible, which would be a basic usability requirement. There are other UI patterns that work better, like a matrix of priorities, select elements to indicate the priority or drag&drop solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added class `.chx` to each checkbox since it's the easiest way to access a group of tags -- I can't think of a reason why you shouldn't. Basically you need to use an event handler to pickup values that are derived from the user interacting with the checkboxes.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Define an empty array
let checks = [];

// Bind each checkbox to the change event
$('.chx').on('change', function() {
  // If the changed checkbox is checked
  if (this.checked) {
    // Add the checkbox's value to the array
    checks.push(+$(this).val());
  } else {
    // Otherwise add a negative value of the checkbox to the array
    checks.push(-$(this).val());
  }
  console.log(checks);
});
/* Added the negative numbers because there's two states a checkbox is in
and if it's important to know the order of what was checked then it's 
probably important to know what state each one is in as well.
*/
```

```html
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class='chx' value="1" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" class='chx' value="2" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" class='chx' value="3" name="mycheck[]">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why should we add the negative value when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: I just add an explanation in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to capture the Javascript [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event when the the state of a checkbox changes. If the change event returns a "checked" state use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add the checkbox value to the `list` array. Otherwise (see `else` block) use the [`grep()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method to remove checkbox values for checkboxes that, upon change, are unchecked.

```js
var list = new Array(); // a place to store the selection order

$('input').on("change", function(e) {
  let boxval = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    list.push(boxval);
  } 
  else {
    list = $.grep(list, function(item) {
     return boxval !== item;
    });
  }

  console.log(list);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck">
```

And for good measure here's a **vanilla Javascript** version which...

...uses [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to collect the target checkboxes then [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the collection in order to add a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event listener to each.

When a checkbox `change` event occurs, and the checked state of the checkbox is `true`, the corresponding checkbox value is [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)'ed to the `list` array.

Alternatively, (again, see `else` block) the Array method [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to remove unchecked box values from the `list` array.

```js
var list = []; // a place to store the selection order

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="mycheck"]').forEach(function (box) {
  box.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    let boxval = evt.target.value;
    if ( true === box.checked ) {
      list.push(boxval);
    }
    else {
      list = list.filter(function(val) {
        return boxval !== val;
      });
    }

    console.log(list);
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```js
    var list = new Array();
    $('input').on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            list.push([$(this).val()]);
        }
        console.log(list);

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck">

    <label for="check-2">check 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck">

    <label for="check-3">check 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck">
```

Hope it will be work :)

Comment: Good answers offer some explanation for what the code does.

Comment: This will only work if the user actually clicks each checkbox, which is a dangerous assumption for states in general. It does not work if the checkboxes get programmatically checked (javascript), already have a `checked` attribute in HTML or if the user navigates back and the browser keeps the checked state. Checkboxes can be checked by means of keyboard as well, but that would work because it triggers `click` events.

Comment: So it’s a good start. You’d need to decide what to do with checked checkboxes where you didn’t receive their `click` event. And to remove checkboxes that get unchecked again.

Comment: Since the question is asking to capture the order the user checks each box I think the click event satisfies the requirement. However this answer does not allow the user to uncheck a box, after checking it, and subsequently removing that box from the "order user checked" array.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes values are unique.*

When checked, push the value to an array.
When unchecked, remove it from the array.

```js
const selections = [];
$('[name="mycheck[]"]').on('change', function (){
  // if checked, add it to the array
  if (this.checked) {
    selections.push(this.value);
  } else {
    // if not checked, remove the value from the array
    const index = selections.indexOf(this.value);
    if (index > -1) selections.splice(index, 1);
  }
  console.log(selections);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck[]">
```

Comment: This is a simple and effective solution, if other ways of checking checkboxes than direct user interaction should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need to **send the order array data to the server**, using the form containing the checkboxes, below is another approach to recording the order checkboxes are checked.

First notice the checkbox names have been changed from `name="mycheck"` to `name="mycheck[]"` to make use of server-side array creation/modification, such as [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

With that in place [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to collect the target checkboxes then iterate the collection in order to add a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event listener to each.

A `change` event handler is used to capture a checked state change for each targeted checkbox. Upon checked state change the number of already checked state checkboxes are counted using `querySelectorAll()` [attribute selectors along with modifier `^=` and pseudo-class `:checked`](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-queryselector/). The count is reduced by one to determine the next available array index.

If the checked state changes to true, the next available array index is added to the checkbox name attribute.

If the checked state changes to false, the target checkbox previously assigned index is captures, the checkbox name is updated to remove the index, and the rest of the checked checkboxes' indexes are updated to reflect the removal of one from the order of selections. Only the checkboxes with an index greater than the target index need to be updated.

[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are used—in the the case of an unchecked state, which means the checkbox was previously checked—to capture the previously assigned index for: 1) capture the target checkbox index to determine which already checked checkboxes need their index decremented, and 2) when looping checked checkboxes in order to decrement all checkboxes having indexes greater than the target index.

```js
// collect and loop inputs with name starting with "mycheck["
document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="mycheck["]').forEach(function (cbox_change) {

  // add a change event listener to each checkbox
  cbox_change.addEventListener("change", function ({target: cbox_order}) {

    // determine the next available index
    let idx_add = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="mycheck["]:checked').length - 1;
  
    // if changed checkbox check state is true (checked)
    if ( cbox_order.checked ) {
      // add next index to name attribute
      cbox_order.name = "mycheck[" + (idx_add) + "]";
    }
    
    // if changed checkbox check state is false (unchecked)
    else {
      // get target index already assigned when changed to true
      let idx_remove = parseInt(cbox_order.name.match(/^mycheck\[([0-9]+)\]$/)[1]);
      // remove index from name
      cbox_order.name = "mycheck[]";
      // loop all checked checkboxes to update indexes greater than target index
      document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="mycheck["]:checked').forEach(function (cbox_update) {
        // capture index to update
        let idx_update = parseInt(cbox_update.name.match(/^mycheck\[([0-9]+)\]$/)[1]);
        // if greater than target index, reduce by one
        if (idx_remove < idx_update) {
          cbox_update.name = "mycheck[" + (idx_update - 1) + "]";
        }
      });
    }

    // show name of all "mycheck" checkboxes
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="mycheck["]').forEach(function (cbox) {
      console.log(cbox.name);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck[]">

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck[]">
```

If you're using [PHP](https://php.net) on the server to access this array, simply:

```
<?php

// get checked order array
$mycheck = $_POST['mycheck'];
// sort by key
ksort($mycheck);

?>
```

And if you need to use the order array in the browser, before the form is uploaded:

```js
let check_order = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="mycheck["]:checked'))
  .sort(function (aa, bb) {
    return aa.name.match(/^mycheck\[([0-9]+)\]$/)[1] - bb.name.match(/^mycheck\[([0-9]+)\]$/)[1];
  })
  .map(function (item) {
    return parseInt(item.value);
  })
;

console.log(check_order);
```

```html
<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck[2]" checked>

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck[0]" checked>

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck[1]" checked>
```

Answer (score -2):

Be careful about *state* in general: User interaction is only one way to change state, and often there are more kinds of interaction possible than you can imagine.

Things often overlooked are state being set programmatically, for example via a “check all” checkbox, and keyboard interaction.

So in general it is better to listen on `change` than on `click`, and to work with the actual state when creating the final list. To symbolise that I created a button.

Also, you’d need to take into account that users can uncheck and check again.

The approach here is to track the order in which each checkbox was checked, and then finally sort the actually checked checkboxes by their position in that kind of log.

```js
const checkedLog = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    checkedLog.push(this.value);
  }
  // only track order in which they were checked, not unchecked
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  // get all actually checked values
  const vals = [];
  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    vals.push(this.value);
  })

  // sort actually checked values by last log entry
  const reverseLog = 
  vals.sort((a, b) => checkedLog.lastIndexOf(a) - checkedLog.lastIndexOf(b));
  console.log(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="check-1">check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" value="1" name="mycheck">

<label for="check-2">check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-2" value="2" name="mycheck" checked>

<label for="check-3">check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-3" value="3" name="mycheck">

<button>get sorted values</button>
```

This is using [Array’s sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and using the log of check events to compare which checkbox should come first.

[`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) is used because the last time the box got checked counts.

You could also remove checkboxes from the log once they get unchecked, then `lastIndex()` would suffice.

Should there be one box checked that did not trigger a `change` event, `lastIndexOf()` would return -1 and that value would be first in the list.